# Java DLL linkage error

Tags: java, dll, linker, usb, libusb

I am using libusb-- http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/libusb-win32/wiki

However, I get:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   USBManager.usb_init()V

```
public class USBManager 
{   
    static{
        System.loadLibrary("libusb");   
    }

    native void usb_init();
    public USBManager()
    {       
        usb_init();     
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just use public native usb_init(); and then load a native library like that, the JNI is not implemented that way.

you use javah to create a .h file the can be used to create a library that implements the specific native functions in the class.

```
javac USBManager
```

Creates a class file, that you use with javah:

```
javah USBManager
```

This yields a file in that location called 'USBManager.h', which specifies the functions to implement in a .so/.dll that implement the relevant native function.

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class USBManager */

#ifndef _Included_USBManager
#define _Included_USBManager
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     USBManager
 * Method:    usb_init
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_USBManager_usb_1init
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

So you need to export a function called 'Java_USBManager_usb_1init', that takes the to parameters specified.

That function can be nothing more than:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_USBManager_usb_1init (JNIEnv *, jobject) {
    usb_init();
}
```

There is a pretty good simple example on [a blog by a Sun developer](http://blogs.oracle.com/moonocean/entry/a_simple_example_of_jni), but there are lots of other examples out there.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [Java wrapper for this library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbjava/) that has already been written. Why don't you try that ?

Comment: Coola, I didn't know there was a java wrapper for the library. That makes things nice and easy for usage

Answer (score 0):

Try  `System.loadLibrary("usb");`

Comment: This is win, not linux. On linux, and shared library called "libabc.so" is referenced by "abc", on win an "libabc.dll" is referenced by "libabc".

Comment: Win? you mean Windows? Ah, sorry, not supporting legacy systems :)

Answer (score 0):

Either the usb.dll cannot be found, try System.load() with an abbsolute path instead of System.loadLibrary(), to verify this.

Another problem might be, that libusb relies on other DLLs. Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see, which DLLs are referenced by libusb.

Another problem might be, that the DLL does not export a function with the corrent Signature. There should be a USBManager_usb_init() function in the DLL. Use `javah` to create the correct signature.

Answer (score 0):

JNI is rather minimalistic, any function accessed by jni requires a native wrapper function written against your class. The tool javah generates a header containing the required wrappers.

To access native functions the easy way use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/).